# Get the currently presented view controller in an app extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I tried to use the KeyWindow but it is not available in an app extension.

Here's what my code looks like :

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentedViewController];
```

It works in the main application but it doesn't work in the app extension.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?